# returning a list using a given type parameter in c#

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

The problem is as follows: I have a method that (should) return a different list with a given type parameter. This is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>() {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Account))
        return GetList().Select(m => m.Coordinator).Distinct();
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Blok))
        return null;
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Curriculum))
        return null;
     else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Program))
        return null;
    return null;
}
```

for most of you the error is obvious: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< Domain.Models.Account>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". This means a cast solves the problem e.g. ("(IEnumerable)" or "as IEnumerable"), but is this the way to go? What is the elegant way of solving this?

Comment: could the down-voter elaborate?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you've made a generic method that can only handle a few types, that's usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that's a good comment, could you give me an example of how that can be written?

Comment: Do you need it to be generic? Why can't you just have methods for GetAccounts(), GetBloks(), GetCurriculums(), GetPrograms()?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Well, I would rather see be in one central method. This way I would not have to add (and thus implement) this in the IRepository. Or is this way of thinking bad / bad programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by simply casting as the error message says

```
return GetList().Select(m => m.Coordinator).Distinct() as IEnumerable<T>;
```

This can be done with a generic repository by simply using an interface. If the class implementing this repository goes agianst a database or not doesnt really matter.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity GetById(object id);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete);
    void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate);
}
```

Example implementation using entity framework: (It doesnt really matter if you use EF or just a mockup class here, you could just replace the context/entities with for example a list)

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    internal ApplicationContext Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> Entities;

    public Repository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        if (Context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        Context = context;
        Entities = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Entities;

        if(filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        query = includeProperties.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));

        return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(object id)
    {
        return Entities.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        Entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = Entities.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (Context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Entities.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        Entities.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        Entities.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Comment: this does indeed solve the problem, but I am not sure if this is an elegant way of solving the problem?

Comment: could you give me an example?